# Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/var/www/appname/storage/logs/lumen.log" could not be opened

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, docker, lumen, aws-cloud9

I am trying to run multiple containers on docker hosted on AWS cloud9, with which all of the services were built using lumen.
I'm not getting header request being passed and hence decided to die dump the  `$request` headers in PHP, hence the cause of the error.

How do I i possibly go about this?
Below is a snippet of my error
[Snippet from error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wg2QL.png)

Comment: Ssh into the docker and give write permission to the process trying to write to the storage folder.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Quesler, but this did not solve the problem. when I still try to access routes the requires header parameters, it does not work. for instance, when I try to access a route protected by auth middle i.e by passing the authentication token as header, it returns 401, unauthorized response. meaning that the header send to the app is not recognized by the app

Comment: This started when I pushed my code to aws c9 and started using docker. on my local machine everthing works fine. May I also point out that other routes that do not require headers to be passed to then are working perfectly well.

Comment: I noticed this error particularly with routes that are protected by auth middleware. now if I pass the same authentication token as body to the route they work. but if I pass the same auth token as body it doesn't work

Comment: could you add some of your relevant code please?